# Playing HLS video throws error in video.js player

Tags: video.js, hls.js

While playing HLS video, getting this error. Though it is not affecting the video player.

Using video.js - 5.9.2,
hls.js: "0.13.3-canary.5394"

```
{"error":"hlsError","event":{"type":"mediaError","parent":"main","details":"bufferAppendError","fatal":false}}
```

Comment: Is there some special reason that you chose a 'canary' named release of HLS?  (Names containing 'canary' are typically NOT 'stable' releases, as can be seen here:  https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/releases  For example, try v0.14.16 and see if that solves it.

Comment: Oh. We didn't know that. Will try with the latest stable version. Let see if that works. Thanks.